# Xcode 8.1 : Entitlements error after adding entitlements file

Tags: ios

I have added entitlements file and set correct path in code signin entitlements

[image]

but still I'm getting

> Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}

Comment: Are you using push notifications?

Comment: you dont have valid provisioning profile , do one thing , just set no code signing to **Target** and **Project** section and then once run in simulator and then Refresh and then close xcode and then generate provisioning profile and download it and set code signing again and run it should fix your issue .

Comment: FYI: i'm using push notification and my certificates are valid

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all and in this case it is solved by : http://www.jianshu.com/p/62f631012853

[image]

in my case : **Any SDK** is present and after removing i got token :)